# Second column defaulting to identity column SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, identity

I have a table `tbl_Customers` with two columns `CustomerID` and `CustomerGroupID`. `CustomerID` is the identity column. When a new record is added, I would like the `CustomerGroupID` value to automatically default to the `CustomerID` value, unless a parameter value is supplied, in which case it should be set to the parameter value.

Here's my stored procedure at the moment (not including the `CustomerGroupID` column)

Many thanks from a SQL Server newbie for any help!

Jim

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AddCustomerUpdateCar] 
            @CarReg varchar(10),
            @CustTitle varchar(8),  
            @CustFName   varchar(15),   
            @CustSName varchar(20),
            @CustCompany varchar(30),   
            @CustTel1   varchar(15),    
            @CustTel2   varchar(15),    
            @CustAddress1 varchar(50),  
            @CustAddress2 varchar(50),  
            @CustAddress3 varchar(50),  
            @CustAddress4 varchar(50),  
            @CustPostCode varchar(9),   
            @CustEmail varchar(50),
            @CustCredit smallmoney,
            @CustCreditExpires datetime,
            @CustAccountID int,
            @CustSource varchar(50)

AS

INSERT INTO tbl_Customers 
            (CustTitle,
            CustFName,
            CustSName,
            CustCompany,
            CustTel1,
            CustTel2,
            CustAddress1,
            CustAddress2,
            CustAddress3,
            CustAddress4,
            CustPostCode,
            CustEmail,
            CustCredit,
            CustCreditExpires,
            CustAccountID,
            CustSource)

VALUES      (@CustTitle,
        @CustFName,
        @CustSName,
        @CustCompany,
        @CustTel1,
        @CustTel2,
        @CustAddress1,
        @CustAddress2,
        @CustAddress3,
        @CustAddress4,
        @CustPostCode,
        @CustEmail,
        @CustCredit,
        @CustCreditExpires,
        @CustAccountID,
        @CustSource)
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us where is `@CustomerGroupID` parameter ...

Comment: Sorry Danihp, I probably need to make it clearer. I have only just added the column to the table, so the stored procedure doesn't reflect this, but it would go in the parameters section, e.g. after @CustSource

Answer (score 1):

You can create a trigger that would set the default after insert:

```
create trigger defaultGroupId on t after insert as
update t set groupID = id where id in (select id from inserted);
```

Here's a fiddle showing it in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e5b2/1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks John,

I think I need to brush up on triggers a little bit more!

In the meantime, I have managed to fix my own problem, adding an UPDATE to the end of my sp. For anyone else with a similar problem, here is the code:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go




ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AddCustomerUpdateCar] @CarReg varchar(10),
                                                @CustTitle  varchar(8), 
                                                @CustFName  varchar(15),    
                                                @CustSName  varchar(20),
                                                @CustCompany    varchar(30),    
                                                @CustTel1   varchar(15),    
                                                @CustTel2   varchar(15),    
                                                @CustAddress1   varchar(50),    
                                                @CustAddress2   varchar(50),    
                                                @CustAddress3   varchar(50),    
                                                @CustAddress4   varchar(50),    
                                                @CustPostCode   varchar(9), 
                                                @CustEmail  varchar(50),
                                                @CustCredit smallmoney,
                                                @CustCreditExpires datetime,
                                                @CustAccountID  int,
                                                @CustSource varchar(50),
                                                @CustomerGroupID int

AS

BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO tbl_Customers (CustTitle,
                            CustFName,
                            CustSName,
                            CustCompany,
                            CustTel1,
                            CustTel2,
                            CustAddress1,
                            CustAddress2,
                            CustAddress3,
                            CustAddress4,
                            CustPostCode,
                            CustEmail,
                            CustCredit,
                            CustCreditExpires,
                            CustAccountID,
                            CustSource)
VALUES (@CustTitle,
        @CustFName,
        @CustSName,
        @CustCompany,
        @CustTel1,
        @CustTel2,
        @CustAddress1,
        @CustAddress2,
        @CustAddress3,
        @CustAddress4,
        @CustPostCode,
        @CustEmail,
        @CustCredit,
        @CustCreditExpires,
        @CustAccountID,
        @CustSource)

IF @customerGroupID = 0 
BEGIN
    UPDATE tbl_Customers
    SET CustomerGroupID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    WHERE CustomerID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END

COMMIT TRAN
```

Answer (score 0):

A small improvement to usefull @John Tsend answer: if it's a **default** value, it can be set with a different value at INSERT time, and that one should not be overwritten.
So I would change the trigger to:

```
create trigger defaultGroupId on t after insert as
update t set groupID = id where id in 
      (select id from inserted where groupId is null);
```